# sign out firebase android studio

Tags: android, firebase, logout

the code is crashing after i log out of the menu activity,it opens the logo activity but it doesn't works and stop working right after

```
else if (id == R.id.nav_sair) {

                AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(RealMenuActivity.this); //Home is name of the activity
                builder.setMessage("Deseja sair?");
                builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                        finish();
                        Intent i=new Intent(RealMenuActivity.this, LogoActivity.class);
                        i.putExtra("finish", true);
                        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); // To clean up all activities
                        //startActivity(i);
                        startActivity( i );
                        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();



                        finish();
                        return;




                    }
                });
```

and this is logo activity ,i think the error is here,but i am not sure

```
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener firebaseAuthListener;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView( R.layout.activity_logo );


        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        firebaseAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {



            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                if (user != null) {

                    Intent it = new Intent( LogoActivity.this, RealMenuActivity.class );
                    startActivity( it );
                    finish();
                    return;
                }

            }
        };

        mEmail = (EditText) findViewById( R.id.Email );
        mPassword = (EditText) findViewById( R.id.Password );
        mbtnLogin = (ImageButton) findViewById( R.id.loginButton );

        mRegistro = (Button) findViewById( R.id.Registro );

        mRegistro.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent it = new Intent(LogoActivity.this, RegistroActivity.class);
                startActivity(it);
            }
        } );

        mbtnLogin.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final String Email = mEmail.getText().toString();
                final String Password = mPassword.getText().toString();
                mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword( Email, Password).addOnCompleteListener( LogoActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()){
                            Toast.makeText( LogoActivity.this, "Erro ao Entrar. Tente novamente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                        }

                    }
                } );
            }
        } );
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener( firebaseAuthListener );
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        if (firebaseAuthListener != null) {
            mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(firebaseAuthListener);
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();

        }
    }
}
```

It crashes right after It opens the logo activity!Soon I will add the logcat!
Can sb help me?Thanks in advance!

Logcat

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to stop activity {com.example.norio.amosou/com.example.norio.amosou.RealMenuActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getUid()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:4331)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:4393)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap6(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1618)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6339)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:945)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getUid()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.norio.amosou.RealMenuActivity.onStop(RealMenuActivity.java:472)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStop(Instrumentation.java:1311)
        at android.app.Activity.performStop(Activity.java:6864)

Comment: the logcat would help also I don't see `auth.signOut();`

Comment: Send the logcat result

Comment: @Emi `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();`?

Comment: already tried the FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();...it still stop working

Answer (score 0):

the reason is that you are doing  2 finish() in your onclick

```
@Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                        finish();
                        Intent i=new Intent(RealMenuActivity.this, LogoActivity.class);
                        i.putExtra("finish", true);
                        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); // To clean up all activities
                        //startActivity(i);
                        startActivity( i );
                        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();



                        finish();
```

just remove the first one because you are killing your activity before accessing your intent and your signout

```
@Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {


                        Intent i=new Intent(RealMenuActivity.this, LogoActivity.class);
                        i.putExtra("finish", true);
                        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); // To clean up all activities
                        //startActivity(i);
                        startActivity( i );
                        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();



                        finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

your mistake is actually trying to do this `FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();` in your firebaseAuthListener.
you didnt use the firebaseAuth in  the `onAuthStateChange`

```java
public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {

}
```

What you were suppose to do wasthis `FirebaseUser user = fireBaseAuth.getCurrecntUser()` instead of this `FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();`